# getNodePath() not showing elements

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

I am attempting to get the XPath for a node using DOMDocuments. However, the response I am getting is `/*/*[2]/*/*[1]/*[1]/*[5]`. Anyone know why this is and/or a possible fix?

My code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(file_get_contents($_FILES["xmlfile"]["tmp_name"]));

$xp  = new DOMXpath($doc);
$domNodeList = $xp->evaluate("//*[@Name]") ;  
foreach($domNodeList as $domNodeListItem)
{
    if(preg_match('/^rectangle.*/i',$domNodeListItem->getAttribute('Name')) === 1)
    {
        echo 'path: <pre>'.print_r($domNodeListItem->getNodePath(),true).'</pre>' ;
    }
}
```

Example XML (the following example gives me `/*/*[1]` and `/*/*[2]` as output, expected is `/Report/Rectangle` and `/Report/MUAHAHA`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
    <Rectangle Name="Rectangle3">
        <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                                <Value />
                                <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
                <Top>0.16667in</Top>
                <Left>0.15625in</Left>
                <Height>0.25in</Height>
                <Width>1in</Width>
                <Style>
                    <Border>
                        <Style>None</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
            </Textbox>
        </ReportItems>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Top>0.66542in</Top>
        <Left>2.53in</Left>
        <Height>2.60417in</Height>
        <Width>1.47917in</Width>
        <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle>
    <MUAHAHA Name="Rectangle123">
        <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="Textbox3">
                <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
                <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
                <Paragraphs>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <TextRuns>
                            <TextRun>
                                <Value />
                                <Style />
                            </TextRun>
                        </TextRuns>
                        <Style />
                    </Paragraph>
                </Paragraphs>
                <rd:DefaultName>Textbox3</rd:DefaultName>
                <Top>0.16667in</Top>
                <Left>0.15625in</Left>
                <Height>0.25in</Height>
                <Width>1in</Width>
                <Style>
                    <Border>
                        <Style>None</Style>
                    </Border>
                    <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                    <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                    <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                    <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
                </Style>
            </Textbox>
        </ReportItems>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Top>0.66542in</Top>
        <Left>2.53in</Left>
        <Height>2.60417in</Height>
        <Width>1.47917in</Width>
        <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
        </Style>
    </MUAHAHA>
</Report>
```

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: I expected the path to contain the element names, not wildcard characters.

Comment: Could you provide a small example XML, so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Added a portion of the test XML I am using to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

The path being returned was due to the default namespace. Apparently neither DOMDocuments nor XPath like this XML feature.

The workaround I used was to remove the default namespace, get the path, then replace it. I will add an example when I have time.

Giving the default namespace a prefix would have been preferred, but that wasn't possible in my case.